# Video Indexer API INVALID_INPUT - indexing preset 'DefaultWithNoiseReduction' is invalid

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-video-indexer

I have been using Video Indexer API to upload video from my application for some time now, and since yesterday I start encountering the `INVALID_INPUT` error.

Here's how I am calling the POST upload API in Python:

```
vi_location = 'southeastasia'
vi_account_id = 'some-account-id'  # replaced with actual account ID
video_language = 'en-US'
name = 'test-video-name'
access_token = 'some-access-token'  # replaced with actual access token generated with AccessToken endpoint

params = {
    'streamingPreset': 'Default',
    'indexingPreset': 'DefaultWithNoiseReduction',
    'language': video_language,
    'name': video_name,
    'accessToken': access_token
}

files = {
    'file': open('some-file-name.mp4', 'rb')
}

upload_video_req = requests.post('https://api.videoindexer.ai/{loc}/Accounts/{acc_id}/Videos'.format(
        loc=vi_location,
        acc_id=vi_account_id
    ),
    params=params,
    files=files
)  # here's where it generates the error message
```

Here's the message generated from the API response.

```
{"ErrorType":"INVALID_INPUT","Message":"Indexing preset \'DefaultWithNoiseReduction\' is invalid. Trace id: \'5086aa05-14d3-4f9a-928e-c2159a14705e"}
```

Based on the documentation, the allowed values for indexing preset is as followed:

```
The indexing preset to use. Allowed values: DefaultWithNoiseReduction/Default/AudioOnly/VideoOnly/Basic/BasicAudio/BasicVideo/Advanced/AdvancedAudio/AdvancedVideo
```

I have tried 2 things:

1. Add the `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` in the request headers, previously doesn't seems to require if I were to pass in the access token
2. Switching `DefaultWithNoiseReduction` to `Default` and that seems to allow the API call to go through, however, it then shows an error in indexing the video after.

[image: Problem Indexing Video]

Manually uploading the video via the console/dashboard seems to work, so it could be just the API endpoints that are having some issues.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

---

*Update 2021-02-01*: Seems like changing the indexing preset to `Default` works now. However, the issue with DefaultWithNoiseReduction still persists.

Comment: You can find that using Default to skip/solve this problem is really clever. The official documents should not be updated, you can raise a support ticket on portal to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

## I think `DefaultWithNoiseReduction` may have been deprecated or merged with `Default`.

If you are interested, you can [rasie a support ticket to confirm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request). Below are my test results.

*Test Steps:*

I [use offical sample code and test it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/video-indexer/upload-index-videos#code-sample), I set  `indexingPreset=DefaultWithNoiseReduction` as below.

```
queryParams = CreateQueryString(
    new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"accessToken", accountInfo.AccessToken},
        {"language", "English"},
        { "indexingPreset","DefaultWithNoiseReduction"}
    }
);
```

When I debug `videoGetIndexResult`, I get `"indexingPreset":"Default",`.

[image]

**According to the test, in C# code, DefaultWithNoiseReduction has been deprecated or ignored, and may be replaced by Default.**

The Python SDK code may not be updated in time. So it led to your previous problem.

**In order to further verify my guess, I found in the `Video Indexer Portal` that in the advanced options, there are only 3 types of indexingPreset left.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for testing it out. As updated in the opening thread I also fallback to using `Default` as a workaround, though the official doc still highlight `DefaultWithNoiseReduction` as a potential option.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/video-indexer/upload-index-videos#indexingpreset